# Semantic Issue with UITextfield

Tags: ios, compiler-errors, uilabel, semantics

I'm new to iOS. I've searched on here for UITextfield Sematic Issues here, as well as variations on that. I'm trying to make a pretty simple app, that you:

Enter text into a text filed
Press A button
It changes a label to the text entered in the text field.

But I keep on getting this strange sematic error and I don't know how to fix it.

Code is here:

The .m file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextField;


@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myLabel;



- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender;

@end
```

The .h

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", [myTextField text]];
    [myLabel setText:message];
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What complier error you are getting? Please post it.

Comment: I implement you code, it work fine ..... what is your error

Comment: @AhmedZ. your statement is not true. Objective C allows access to properties as well as methods with this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are referencing your properties directly without a "self.". Replace your m file contents with this:

```
@interface ViewController ()


@end
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", [self.myTextField text]];
    [self.myLabel setText:message];
}

@end
```

Comment: Your solution was right as well, I needed to reference the self. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm expecting error like `unknown Reciever 'myTextField'` error it means,

in IOS 6 apple providing Synthesize property by default so you can use

Either

```
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", [_myTextField text]];
```

or

```
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@", [self.myTextField text]];
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you so much , I was referencing it without the self at the front.